# Adafruit MAX 31856 communicating with raspberrypi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, adafruit, thonny

I have been trying to read a thermocouple temperature on my raspberrypi however cant get the raspi to communicate with the adafruit MAX 31856. I have downloaded necessary libraries and checked that all connections are secure and correct however keep running into this error when I try to execute this code.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

**CODE**

```
   import board 
   import digitalio 
   import adafruit_max31856 
   spi = board.SPI() 
   cs = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D5) 
   cs.direction = digitalio.Direction.OTUPUT 
   thermocouple = adafruit_max31856.MAX31856(spi,cs) 
   print(thermocouple.temperature)
```

**ERROR:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 

  File "/home/pi/test4.py", line 6, in <module> 

    spi = board.SPI() 

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/board.py", line 299, in SPI 

    return busio.SPI(SCLK, MOSI, MISO) 

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/busio.py", line 289, in __init__ 

    self._spi = _SPI(portId) 

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/adafruit_blinka/microcontroller/generic_linux/spi.py", line 25, in __init__ 

    self._spi = spi.SPI(device=(portid, 0)) 

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/Adafruit_PureIO/spi.py", line 167, in __init__ 

    raise IOError("{} does not exist".format(device)) 

OSError: /dev/spidev0.0 does not exist
```

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyTA6.jpg)
[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3E850.jpg)

Comment: [raspberry pi 4B no /dev/spidev0.0](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/130985)

Answer (score 0):

Most probably there is a device driver loaded for spi0-0 and that removes /dev/spidev0.0 device.
check your /boot/config.txt for overlays loading MAX 31856 driver module.
if you want to use adafruit_max31856 lib you shouldn't be loading this driver. hope that helps